# .net SortedList with StringComparer and german umlaut

Tags: .net, sortedlist, currentculture

I have a SortedList with streetnames

```
Dim orderedListStreet As New Generic.SortedList(Of String, String)(StringComparer.CurrentCulture)
```

Lets take for example, the list already contains "`Hauptstrasse`"

If I add "`Hauptstraße`", it throws an exception -> `Key does already exist`

Does anyone have an idea how I can add "`Hauptstrasse`" and "`Hauptstraße`" ?

Comment: That's an esset not an unlaut. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esset

Comment: Can someone tell me why the same exception is thrown if `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` is used?

Comment: `InvariantCulture` still knows about unicode equivalencies, you need `Ordinal` if you really want to compare the codepoints.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a comparer that considers them to be different.  In Germany I'd expect Hauptstrasse and Hauptstraße to be the same street, so it's logical that a German culture will consider them to be equal.

Which one to use will depend on your needs - the fastest will be `StringComparer.Ordinal` or `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

If you want culture-sensitive sorting, but want to consider as distinct two strings that your culture considers to be identical, one solution would be to implement your own comparer, for example:

```
int MyComparer(string x, string y)
{
    var result = StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(x,y);
    if (result == 0) result = StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x,y);
    return result;
}
```

This sorts based on CurrentCulture, but breaks ties using an ordinal sort (you could replace this by something else if it doesn't meet your needs).